# List imported modules from an imported module in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to have a list of the names and files of imported modules form an imported module, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('someModule')

for mod in module.modules():
    print(mod.name)
    print(mod.file)
```

Comment: Do you want only modules imported directly by `someModule`, or also those imported implicitly as a result of those imports?

Comment: @BradSolomon The second one. If I have the first I can have the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python3 lets us pull in the module with `exec(f'import {module_name}')`, putting the result in `globals()[module_name]`,
or we can assign `mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)`.

To see what *other* modules were directly pulled in by that, use:

```
def is_module(x):
    return str(type(x)) == "<class 'module'>"


def show_deps(mod):
    for name in dir(mod):
        val = getattr(mod, name)
        if is_module(val):
            print(name, val.__file__)
```

One could recurse through the tree to find transitive deps, if desired.